# How do I configure Windows Server 2008 R2 to allow sending of email from an Integrated Services Package in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, smtp, windows-server-2008

How do I configure Windows Server 2008 R2 to allow sending of email from an Integrated Services Package in SQL Server?

I am trying to send an email from an SSIS package that that has been imported into the MSDB stored packages.

When I run the package I get the below error:

> [Send Mail Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error
>   message: "Failure sending mail.  System.Net.WebException: Unable to
>   connect to the remote server  System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An
>   attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access
>   permissions

I have tried the same thing using a script task and `MailMessage()` and `SmtpClient()` in .NET and the task does not fail but it also does not send the email.

As a sidenote: I know there is a website setup on the server through IIS that is able to send emails via port 25.

I have given the package the same host IP address and port number, but it I still get an error.

Does anyone know what I can troubleshoot for finding a way to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the server had changed to use something other than the default TCP port.

The SSIS send email task only supports port 25, so I updated the script tasks and used them.

Answer (score 0):

Does the package send the email successfully when running in debug mode on your dev workstation?  If so, then I'm guessing the SMTP server is denying the SQL Server Integration Services server permission to connect. Perhaps the ip address of the SSIS server needs to be granted connect and/or relay permission in the SMTP product?

To test this, and other connectivity issues, telnet from the SSIS server to the SMTP server on port 25 (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153119).

Additionally, set up Database Mail in SQL Server Database Services and test email from there. This also tests that the SMTP server allows the SSIS/MSSSQL server to connect and send mail.

Always test using both an internal email address and an external email address - that way you test relay permissions as well.

Comment: I have tried it from my dev workstation and it doesn't send an email, I get the same error. I will look at what you have suggested. Thanks

Comment: Need to check that the server target is specified correctly in the Connection Manager. Was getting the same error when I had Typo in the SMTP ServerName.